# Facebook app writing comments?

Tags: facebook, api, comments

I know it sounds weird but is there a way that an app (facebook app) that could write a comment on user's picture using Facebook API or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a user can give an app permission to do so via the API.

Comment: Does that mean it show as "user" posting a comment? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes it will.  And it will also have the "via APP_NAME" in the corner - so that people will know that that post was generated from that application.

Comment: I guess that could work! I was thinking of making the app post a comment but since it will have "via APP_NAME" it would be fine =)